# Arrows as tick marks on graph [LaTeX]

Tags: graph, latex, tikz, arrows

I'm trying to draw arrows coming in and out of the following graph. This is aimed at explaining how a function transforms the input numbers. I am just looking to make the ticks as up arrows for the x axis and left arrow for the y axis.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
  xmin=0,     xmax=3.5,
  ymin=0,     ymax=10, 
  xtick={2.4,0.3,1.7,3.2},
  ytick={4, 7, 9},
  xticklabels={$x_1$,$x_2$,$x_3$,$x_4$},
  yticklabels={$y_1$,$y_2=y_3$,$y_4$},
  xticklabel style={/tikz/yshift=-15pt},
  yticklabel style={/tikz/xshift=-15pt}
]
  \addplot[mark=none, smooth] {-2*x^2+4*x+6};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you !